# How to start windowing system(in other words UI) of Ubuntu on WSL windows

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-18.04

I used to start the WSL Ubuntu UI(windowing system) from windows 10 machine.  On the same machine it suddenly stopped working. What could be the reason and how to fix it? I am still able to get terminal(s) by clocking on Unbutu from windows start menu.
[image]

[image]

The setup was done using the method described at https://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-enable-wsl2-ubuntu-gui-and-use-rdp-to-remote.

Comment: You'll need to provide more detail.  Are you attempting to run WSLg on a Windows Preview release?  What is your configuration?  You can't *start* WSL with remote desktop, you'd first need to start it with the `wsl` command.  Have you done that?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds It is Windows 10 Enterprise, my work machine. Is there any command  or  configuration file where I can find the configuration you are want? About "You can't start WSL with remote desktop, you'd first need to start it with the wsl command.", yes, I can see Ubuntu 18.4 LTS at the bottom left usual windows start /search items and launch it to get terminal of ubuntu.

Comment: You say "it suddenly stopped working", but by default WSL Ubuntu doesn't include the capability to access it with Remote Desktop, so I'm trying to figure out what your configuration was that allowed you to do this before.  There's a Kali ([Win-KeX](https://www.kali.org/docs/wsl/win-kex/) distribution that has that capability, but you specifically say you are running Ubuntu, not Kali.  What you are seeing ("Remote Desktop can't connect") is *expected* behavior with WSL Ubuntu, so I'm trying to figure out what you had done (i.e. how you configured it) before to make it work.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I added a link by editing my question. By going through the article you may find what enabled the capability. Please let me know if you find it. Now I am able to solve the problem  (as described in the answer).  Thanks, your questions helped me in thinking in the right direction. I am upvoting your comments.

Comment: Note that even though "remote desktop connection" is used , it is remoting to the same/local machine, just to the linux system of it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get linux terminal(aka command prompt) by clicking on Ubuntu at Windows start menu.
2. 

```
 >sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp status
[sudo] password for admin:
 xrdp-sesman is not running
 xrdp is not running
```

3. ```
     >sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp start
     Starting Remote Desktop Protocol server
                                                                                                             [20210606-10:52:59] [DEBUG] Testing if xrdp can listen on 0.0.0.0 port 3390
   ```

   [20210606-10:52:59] [DEBUG] Closed socket 6 (AF_INET6 :: port 3390)
4. 

```
>sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp status
 * xrdp-sesman is running
 * xrdp is running
```

Now attempt to login using Remote Desktop connection. Press "connect" as shown in the first picture of the OP. You will be prompted for your Linux login. Enter password  and  you will get full-fledged linux UI.